# How can I debug without enable ADB integration

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, ddms

Upon issue I posted yesterday, I re-install Android studio 1.5.1 (the previous version was 2.1 beta). I am able to open DDMS to debug correctly because I can instant run the app with the ENABLE ADB INTEGRATION unchecked which has to be checked before. Can anyone has any idea what happened here? why am I able to debug the app without enable ADB integration? 
Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208467/why-ddms-will-disable-adb-integration-in-android-studio here is the link of issue yesterday

Answer (score 5):

I believe that is solution, i happen that help you

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is how to open ADB integration. I was asking I am now able to debug without this option checked but I had to check it before. I would like to know the reason. I dont want to meet the same problem I met before.